# Need help understanding Toru Tsujishita' theorem on Triple Information

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, information-theory, mutual-information

I struggling to understand point (ii) of Toru Tsujishita's theorem ([here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82716721.pdf)) on Triple- (Interaction- or Co-) Information

- What is meant with the maps $\varphi_j$ and $\varphi_k$? A biunivocal relationship? Any example?
- Does the theorem hold also for discrete variables?

Comment: "Map" is a synonym for "function."  Your second question is difficult to fathom, because the entire paper is explicitly about a limited class of discrete variables: see the first sentence in the first section and notice the word "finite."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first question, point (ii) of Theorem 1 states (in more concrete notation) that for any three finite range random variables $f_1,f_2,f_3$ we have that
$$
I(f_1,f_2,f_3)=H(f_1)
$$
if and only if both the following statements are true:

- $f_1$ is completely determined by $f_2$
- $f_1$ is completely determined by $f_3$

As for an example, if $f_2,f_3$ are independent and not concentrated on a single value, then the only $f_1$ satisfying the two conditions is a constant function.

Regarding the second question, I believe that the results of the paper you cited extend from the case of finite-range random variables to the case of random variables with countable support (i.e., discrete variables). They extend from the finite range case by standard limiting arguments, since all the identities in the paper you cited have a bounded number of terms.